# Modal not displaying

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to bootstrap I'm having trouble with my navbar I don't want to display the collapsed heading when the page is first opened on a mobile is there any way to do this? I have tried searching the web and have had no luck.

My code is:

```
<!-- Menu -->
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#example">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a href="Index.html" class="navbar-brand">The CO-OP Couch</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collpase navbar-collapse" id="example">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="Podcast.html">PodCasts</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Facebook</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Community</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact" data-toggle="modal">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear can you ellaborate. If you want to make accordian by deafult open there is class "collapse in" in bootstrap. Also you can show div on the basis of screen size using class visible-sm or visible-md etc

Comment: When i open the page on a mobile the navbar is automatically open by default which then requires two clicks on the toggle to close. i would like to have the header minimized if that is possible. 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> I think this is what your asking for by the div ?

Answer (score 0):

It was all good just the typo error in your class "collapse".

```
  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#example">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a href="Index.html" class="navbar-brand">The CO-OP Couch</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="example">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="Podcast.html">PodCasts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Facebook</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Community</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact" data-toggle="modal">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank You so much for your help